# Получение переменных из строки,нарисованной на форме

Tags: winforms, pascalabc.net

При решении возникла такая необходимость как взятие строковых значений с формы(ориентируясь на их координаты расположения) и использовать их как параметры для процедуры и переменные.

Вот собственно что пытаюсь сделать
Вот моё дерево нарисованное

Рисую с помощью таких функций как

```
gr.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(565, 180, 35, 35)); // значение правого поддерева(правое)
```

А значение показано внизу,где montekarlo - это число,которое получено с помощью процедуры montekarlo

```
gr.DrawString(montekarlo(diap1, diap2).ToString('N2'), new System.Drawing.Font('Times New Roman', 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 440, 90);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я хочу ориентируясь на координаты считать эти 2 значения в свою процедуру(которая прекрасно работает но на консоли).

После процедуры они изменятся и вернутся на свои места(Но это я пока не рассматриваю в этом вопросе)
Пока важно узнать как их "затолкать в процедуру"

Как мне сделать так чтобы занести эти 2 числа в параметры для процедуры и в переменные?

(код самой процедуры не выкладываю,так как он пока не важен)

Конечно были попытки сделать что-то страшное и ужасное,но компилятор сразу же забил тревогу.Оно и понятно.

```
//1-ое число //    
    var S1:= gr.DrawString(montekarlo(diap1, diap2).ToString('N2'), new System.Drawing.Font('Times New Roman', 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 345, 190);

//2-ое число //   
var S2:= gr.DrawString(montekarlo(diap1, diap2).ToString('N2'), new System.Drawing.Font('Times New Roman', 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular), System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 405, 190);
```

Comment: Координаты относительно чего конкретно? относительно самого дерева или относительно канвы формы? Да и вопрос не до конца ясен. Вы рисуете дерево как вы его рисуете? как вы отображаете значения, где вы их храните?

Comment: Подредактировал вопрос,координаты канвы формы

Comment: тогда вопрос: почему именно по координатам? Если же все таки Вам нужно именно по координатам, можно сделать следующее: Создаете массив который хранит список ваших объектов + координаты этих объектов на канве. После чего легко можно достать из массива объект по координатам, изменить значения объектов, и отрисовать канву заново

Comment: Я на координаты ориентируюсь потому что
1)Когда рисую DrawEllipse то координаты задаю
2)DrawString координаты числа опять же через координаты и поэтому я решил что лучше всего ориентироваться на координаты

Comment: Метод `DrawString` ничего не возвращает. Невозможно получить с канвы `Graphics` нарисованную ранее строку. Храните координаты и строки в специальной коллекции.